# Trying to get an iOS lap timer app to display in thousands instead of tenths

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an iOS lap timer app. It works but will only display in tenths of seconds. I need it to display in thousands. Below is the code from the .m file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am currently setting it up on GitHub if you need to look at the entire app. It's based on an app from another developer that has yet to answer any of my questions.

I'm able to work in Xcode fairly well and can do some basic coding but this above my ability.

```
-(void)targetMethod:(id)sender {
self.mainTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02.0f:%04.1f", [self  totalElapsedInMinutes], [self totalElapsedInSeconds]];

self.lapTimer.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02.0f:%04.1f", [self  timeElapsedInMinutes], [self timeElapsedInSeconds]];
}

- (NSDate *)userInfo {
return [NSDate date];
}

- (double) timeElapsedInSeconds {
return [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:self.runStart];
}

- (double) timeElapsedInMinutes {
return [self timeElapsedInSeconds] / 60.0f;
}

- (double) totalElapsedInSeconds {
NSNumber *totalTime = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:0];

for(id lap in self.laps) {
    totalTime = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([totalTime doubleValue] + [(NSNumber*)lap  doubleValue])];
}

totalTime = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:([totalTime doubleValue] + [self timeElapsedInSeconds])];

return [totalTime doubleValue];
}

- (double) totalElapsedInMinutes {
return [self totalElapsedInSeconds] / 60.0f;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried actually reading the documentation?

Comment: Yes, several times and each time it's more confusing than the last time I read it.

Comment: In this particular case (after your edit) the format syntax is exactly the same as for regular C `printf` statements, so it should be intimately familiar to you before you even start coding Objective-C.  And if you look at the `stringWithFormat` doc it points you to "[String Format Specifiers](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265)".  What precisely was hard to understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The display format is incorrect, see: [Formatting Dates and Times](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime)

```
[self.dateFormat setDateFormat:@"mm:ss.S"];
```

should be:

```
[self.dateFormat setDateFormat:@"mm:ss.SSS"];
```

Better yet use the time interval method:

```
- (NSTimeInterval)timeIntervalSinceDate:(NSDate *)anotherDate
```

divide the seconds to get the minutes and milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed- needed to change the following string. [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02.0f:%04.1f" to [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02.0f:%04.3f"